# Georeferencing Cadastral map in DWG using AutoCAD Map 3D?

Tags: georeferencing, dwg, autocad-map

I want to georeference a cadastral map in dwg format. I have the lat-long of 3+ points on the map but do not have the scale.

I tried "Set Location" in Autocad Map 3D but it references using the lat/long & direction for only one point and then one has to scale the map. I do not have a scale.

How do I georeference the map without a scale?